# Popup Menu won't change its selected state

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have this code here, I created a popup menu when the user long-presses the "edit_text" view's area which displays a popup menu with "Red" "Yellow" radio button option which changes the background color of the "text_view", but I'm not sure why when I select the other option, like when red is currently selected, I select yellow and the other way around(I have the red option selected as the default state), the selected state does not change at all, red is still selected no matter how many times I press yellow. Could you guys help me with this please? Thank you very much.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edit_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);
    text_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //==========_CREATE A POPUP MENU WHEN LONG-CLICK ON EDITTEXT AREA_==========\\

    edit_text.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            final PopupMenu pop_up = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, pop_up.getMenu());

            //GROUP'S ID IS "group".
            pop_up.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group, true, true);

            pop_up.show();

            pop_up.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
            return true;
        }
    });


}   
OnMenuItemClickListener listener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.red:
            text_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            if (!item.isChecked()) {

                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.yellow:
            text_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            if (!item.isChecked()) {

                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
};
protected Context getContext() {
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's some logical issue with your code. Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable):

> When a checkable item is selected, the system calls your respective
>   item-selected callback method (such as onOptionsItemSelected()). It is
>   here that you must set the state of the checkbox, because a checkbox
>   or radio button does not change its state automatically.

It's easy to observe that yours `onLongClick(View v)` get called every time and so the menu gets created every long click again (with initial items states). To fix the issue you can store checked / unchecked state (or current color) some there and set item states properly every time in `onLongClick(View v)`. Like the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private TextView mText;
    // For persistent storage SharedPreferences should be used instead of local variable
    private int mColor = Color.RED;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);

        mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mText.setBackgroundColor(mColor);

        edit.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLongClick");
                final PopupMenu pop_up = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
                final Menu menu = pop_up.getMenu();

                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, menu);

                //GROUP'S ID IS "group".
                menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.group, true, true);

                pop_up.show();

                switch(mColor) {
                    case Color.RED:
                        menu.findItem(R.id.yellow).setChecked(false);
                        menu.findItem(R.id.red).setChecked(true);
                        break;

                    case Color.YELLOW:
                        menu.findItem(R.id.red).setChecked(false);
                        menu.findItem(R.id.yellow).setChecked(true);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                pop_up.setOnMenuItemClickListener(mMenuItemClickListener);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    final OnMenuItemClickListener mMenuItemClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.red:
                    mText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    mColor = Color.RED;
                    return true;

                case R.id.yellow:
                    mText.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    mColor = Color.YELLOW;
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    };
```

Also, I'd suggest to checkout [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html) which provides slightly more convenient way for creating long-click context menus. Please note that documentation of `ContextMenu` from [onCreateContextMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu%28android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo%29) clearly states that menu in proper state should be populated by the app every time:

> Called when a context menu for the view is about to be shown. Unlike
>   onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu), this will be called every time the context
>   menu is about to be shown and should be populated for the view (or
>   item inside the view for AdapterView subclasses, this can be found in
>   the menuInfo)).